# Tikz node alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, nodes

How can I align (or shift) Tikz nodes?
I have the following figure (see below), which consists of multiple horizontal nodes.
I want to align the data node with top/bottom of nodes A-D (i.e., red lines).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5.5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{edge} = [draw]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3.3cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [draw, cylinder, shape border rotate=90, aspect=0.75, %
      minimum height=40, minimum width=60] (data) {Data};
    \node [block, right of=data] (A) {A};
    \node [block, right of=A] (B) {B};
    \node [block, right of=B] (C) {C};
    \node [block, right of=C] (D) {D};
    \path [line] (data) -- (A);
    \path [line] (A) -- (B);
    \path [line] (B) -- (C);
    \path [line] (C) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! Have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an appropriate anchor for the "Data" node to place the node "A" with respect to theis anchor; notice also that `right of=...` is a deprecated syntax and one should use the `positioning` library with the `right=of...` syntax. I also changed the old `\tikzstyle` syntax to the newer `\tikzset` syntax.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,positioning}

\tikzset{
block/.style={
  rectangle,
  draw,
  text width=5.5em,
  text centered,
  rounded corners,
  minimum height=4em},
line/.style={draw, -latex'},
edge/.style={draw}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Place nodes
    \node [draw, cylinder, shape border rotate=90, aspect=0.75, %
      minimum height=40, minimum width=60] (data) {Data};
    \node [block, right=2cm of data.south,anchor=south west] (A) {A};
    \node [block, right= of A] (B) {B};
    \node [block, right=of B] (C) {C};
    \node [block, right=of C] (D) {D};
    \path [line] (data.east|-A.west) -- (A.west);
    \path [line] (A) -- (B);
    \path [line] (B) -- (C);
    \path [line] (C) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Qrrbrbirlbel** suggested in his comment, one can define an auxiliary coordinate at `(data.shape center -| data.east)` and this allows to use `right=of data-center east` for the "A" node; this approach has the advantage that it allows to keep the original node distance:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,positioning}

\tikzset{
block/.style={
  rectangle,
  draw,
  text width=5.5em,
  text centered,
  rounded corners,
  minimum height=4em},
line/.style={draw, -latex'},
edge/.style={draw}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Place nodes
    \node [draw, cylinder, shape border rotate=90, aspect=0.75, %
      minimum height=40, minimum width=60] (data) {Data};
% auxiliary coordinate to place the following node
    \coordinate (data-center east) at (data.shape center -| data.east);
    \node [block, right=of data-center east] (A) {A};
    \node [block, right= of A] (B) {B};
    \node [block, right=of B] (C) {C};
    \node [block, right=of C] (D) {D};
    \path [line] (data.east|-A.west) -- (A.west);
    \path [line] (A) -- (B);
    \path [line] (B) -- (C);
    \path [line] (C) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you define `\coordinate (data-center east) at (data.shape center -| data.east);` you can do `right=of data-center east` while retaining the original `node distance`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I incorporated your suggestion to my answer. Thanks.