# Tikz cylinder alignment and fit

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, fit

I've tried fitting a cylinder to the height of both a block and another cylinder as shown in the code below. Cylinder 2 should fit exactly to the top edge of Block 1 and the bottom edge of Cylinder 1, respectively. When I use only blocks instead of the two cylinders, it works as intended. The red lines in the picture indicate the desired bounds of Cylinder 2.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}

\tikzstyle{b}=[draw, minimum height=2.5em]
\tikzstyle{c}=[draw, minimum height=5em, minimum width=4em, cylinder, shape border rotate=90, shape aspect=0.1]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (block1) [b, anchor=north] {Block 1};
    \node (cylinder1) [c, below=of block1] {Cylinder 1};

    \node (cylinder2) [c, right=3cm of block1.north east,
    anchor=north, fit=(block1)(cylinder1)] {Cylinder 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: minimal example]

Comment: Maybe help this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125790/tikz-node-alignment?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fit` always tries to fit its contents and hence the shape is always larger. You can change `yscale` and do some other settings so that you get what you want. Ugly and manual, but it does it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit,calc}

\tikzstyle{b}=[draw, minimum height=2.5em]
\tikzstyle{c}=[draw, minimum height=5em, minimum width=4em, cylinder, shape border rotate=90, shape aspect=0.1]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (block1) [b, anchor=north,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {Block 1};
    \node (cylinder1) [c, below= 2cm of block1,outer sep=0pt] {Cylinder 1};

    \node (cylinder2) [c, right=3cm of block1.east,
    anchor=north, fit=(block1)(cylinder1),inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,yscale=0.942,yshift=-0.38ex] {Cylinder 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]